# Eclipse indigo- Oracle 11 - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, oracle11g

I have made a Database development in eclipse and i have made the connection and it's working fine.

But when i try a basic query, i'm getting this ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error.

Here's my simple query;

```
CREATE TABLE app.posts (
post_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), 
postname VARCHAR(50),
comments VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
);
```

I don't know what's exactly missing here. 
Someone please help. !!

Comment: remove the , here (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)

Comment: @Satya: Did so... no any different.. Still the same error comes.

Comment: 'generated as identity' was added in 12c. In 11g you'd still need to use a trigger and sequence for this.